# Select first non-NA value by row

Tags: r, multiple-columns, na, missing-data

I have data like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3, 4), A=c(6, NA, NA, 4), B=c(3, 2, NA, NA), C=c(4, 3, 5, NA), D=c(4, 3, 1, 2))

   id A  B  C D
1  1  6  3  4 4
2  2 NA  2  3 3
3  3 NA NA  5 1
4  4  4 NA NA 2
```

For each row: If the row has non-`NA` values in column "A", I want that value to be entered into a new column 'E'. If it doesn't, I want to move on to column "B", and that value entered into E. And so on. Thus, the new column would be `E = c(6, 2, 5, 4)`.

I wanted to use the `ifelse` function, but I am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: (No need to apologize for lack of experience! Good first question, btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, E = coalesce(A, B, C, D))
#   id  A  B  C D E
# 1  1  6  3  4 4 6
# 2  2 NA  2  3 3 2
# 3  3 NA NA  5 1 5
# 4  4  4 NA NA 2 4
```

`coalesce` is effectively *"return the first non-`NA` in each vector"*. It has a SQL equivalent (or it is an equivalent of SQL's `COALESCE`, actually).

### base R

```r
df$E <- apply(df[,-1], 1, function(z) na.omit(z)[1])
df
#   id  A  B  C D E
# 1  1  6  3  4 4 6
# 2  2 NA  2  3 3 2
# 3  3 NA NA  5 1 5
# 4  4  4 NA NA 2 4
```

`na.omit` removes all of the `NA` values, and `[1]` makes sure we always return *just the first* of them. The advantage of `[1]` over (say) `head(., 1)` is that `head` will return `NULL` if there are no non-`NA` elements, whereas `.[1]` will always return at least an `NA` (indicating to you that it was the only option).

Comment: A side-note: if OP is happy with non-`base`: `data.table::fcoalesce` takes a `data.frame`, so then it's possible to do `df$E = fcoalesce(df[-1])`, without entering all individual columns.